# Chef Knife - Error Synch with Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I did a change in recipe and after merge with my master on GitHub, I want to synch my repo with Chef server, I have tried to write a some different commands, such as:

```
knife upload site-cookbooks/my_cookbook
knife upload cookbook site-cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes
```

in any case I get the next error:

> ERROR: Chef::ChefFS::FileSystem::OperationNotAllowedError: Chef::ChefFS::FileSystem::OperationNotAllowedError

Can anybody help me to synch my repo with Chef server?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`knife cookbook upload <cookbook_name>`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html#upload).

Comment: thank you, StephenKing, my mistake is a giving a full path.